# Equation for square law circuit modulator

Tags: modulation, fourier, amplitude-modulation

For DSBFC AM (double side band full carrier amplitude modulation ) the message signal \$m(t)\$ must be multiplied by carrier maybe $$ A_c\cos(\omega_c(t)) $$
(For modulation)

This modulation is done in reality by using the non-linear characteristics of the diode, where

$$ i(t)=av + bv^2 $$

\$v =\$ applied voltage to diode

Here we apply

$$ v =V_c(t)+V_m(t)$$
$$  i(t)=a(V_c+_Vm)+b(V_c+V_m)^2 $$
$$  i(t)= aV_c +bV_m +bV_c^2+bV_m^2 +2V_cV_m $$

Here $$V_c=A_c\cos(\omega_c(t))$$

Thus
$$i(t)=aA_c\cos(\omega_c(t))+bm(t)+b(A_c\cos(\omega_c(t)))^2 +bm(t)^2 +2m(t)A_c\cos(\omega_c(t))$$

After simplification

$$i(t)=aA_c\cos(\omega_c(t))+bm(t)+\frac{bA_c}{2} +\frac{bA_c\cos(2\omega_c(t))}{2} +bm(t)^2 +2m(t)A_c\cos(\omega_c(t))$$

In frequency domain I can clearly understand following components

$$ f(\text{message frequency}),f_c,f_c+f,f_c-f,2f_c $$

but my book tells me there are additional components at \$2f_m\$.

Can someone help me understand where it is?

Comment: \$2f_m\$ would be from the message frequency term \$(m(t))^2\$. e.g. \$\cos^2(2\pi\ f_m t)\$.

Comment: What makes us assume my message signal is cos or sin. Couldn't it be anything maybe my voice or music? @AJN

Comment: The book I am referring is electronic communication by frenkel. It actually ignores the higher order because they become very small.It just considered 2 @rpm2718

Comment: @NewtonNadar Good question. Multiplication of a signal with itself \$(m(t))^2\$ in time domain is represented in frequency domain as a convolution of the signal spectrum with itself \$M(s) \circledast M(s)\$. When a signal is convolved with itself, it becomes twice as wide; i.e., frequency content has values up to twice the the original value. [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Convolution_of_box_signal_with_itself.gif). This is what books mentions as  \$2f_m\$; even if signal was non sinusoidal.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I needed(Does it mean convolution becomes multiplication in Frequency domain and multiplication becomes convolution in Frequency Domain?) .@AJN

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Convolution_theorem_for_inverse_Fourier_transform)

Comment: @AJN Just one thing I want to confirm constants have no effect in frequency domain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115201/discussion-between-ajn-and-newton-nadar).

Comment: "What makes us assume the message signal is cos or sin"  It makes the analysis easier because we can use trig product formulae. Fourier analysis allows more complicated (repetitive) modulating signals to be broken down into a series of sin and cos terms allowing the analysis for a single sin or cos signal to be validly extended to a more complicated signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2fm

This frequency comes from the message signal; specifically \$(m_{(t)})^2\$. Multiplication of a signal with another (or itself) in time domain is represented in frequency domain as a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Convolution_theorem_for_inverse_Fourier_transform).
So the corresponding signal in frequency domain is

$$
M(s) \circledast M(s)
$$

If a signal with frequency contents from 0 to \$f_{max}\$ is convolved with itself, the resulting spectrum will have frequency content from 0 to \$2f_{max}\$.

From [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Convolution_of_box_signal_with_itself.gif)

[image: From wikipedia. convolution with itself]